# Mesoderm vs Mesenchyme- what's the difference?

Tags: embryology

My embryology textbook states that mesoderm can exist as Mesenchyme or Epithelium. I'm not sure what 'epithelium' means. Here is a quote for context:

> Somatic, splanchnic, and somite mesoderm can be temporarily an epithelium.
>   The temporary epithelium transforms to a secondary mesenchyme

What does this quote mean?

Answer (score 2):

Mesenchyme is the meshwork of embryonic connective tissue in the mesoderm; from it are formed the connective tissues of the body as well as blood vessels and lymph vessels.
**So it's a part of mesoderm**

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE...thanks for taking a stab at this answer. We always appreciate some references/links for answers so other users can read more about your answer. It will definitely help the strength of your answer as well.